# linear gradient divs group

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have such an element in the layout. It is inserted by a picture (png)
In connection with the fact that I need to do adaptive, carinka does not suit me. Is it possible to apply a gradient as a child element?

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #4747f6 0%, #f27d66 100%);
```

[image: linear-gtadient png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea is to rely on `background-attachment:fixed` and you will be able to apply gradient to each element and the result will be like you have one gradient:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #4747f6 0%, #f27d66 100%) center/100% 4px no-repeat;
}

.container>div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #4747f6 0%, #f27d66 100%) fixed;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  height: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #4747f6 0%, #f27d66 100%) fixed;
}

.container:after {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: A fantastic solution - you're just missing the small circles at the very start and end of the line

Comment: @Scoots added ;)